# Input-like Python function in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

It may be a stupid question, but I just start my journey with PowerShell.

What I'm trying to archive is to create Input-like `cmdlt` in PowerShell, the same as in Python.
By that, I mean that I search for `cmdlt` that will execute something like this:

```
searched_user = str(input('Please input your AD user name: '))
```

but in PowerShell

Read-Host is not sufficient for my needs. I understand and treat it like `print` in Python.

I tried Read-Host but this is good for prompting something.

Comment: Not an answer, but just a general pointer.  You can read the help items for powershell right in your browser.  Example is,  Help Read-Host.

Comment: `Read-Host` _does_ support prompting the user; see [Microsoft Learn on `Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Why is Read-Host "not sufficient" for your needs? What is it that `input()` does that `Read-Host` doesn't?

Comment: @MichaelMao are you directing this comment to me? Because it is unclear for me.

Comment: @Gveir Sorry. It's my operation mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you added `Read-Host` is off limits. However I would still like you to look if this example would point you to right direction:

```
$serverName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Server name to process'
if ($serverName) {
    Write-Host "We can now use the server name [$serverName] in our code"
} else {
    Write-Warning -Message "No server name input."
}
```

[Source](https://adamtheautomator.com/read-host/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, I manage to solve my mystery with simple solution. It looks like this:  `$searched_ad_user = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your AD user namer here: '
$users = Get-AdUser -Identity $searched_ad_user -Properties DirectReports | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectReports`